# Revisit $a+b+c = 2n+1, a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z}, 1 \leq a,b,c \leq n.$

Tags: combinatorics

This is a self-answer question, which revisits
[this recently deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684467/how-many-uniqe-options-ther-is-for-abc-2n1-and-non-of-the-number-is-greater).

$\underline{\text{The Original Question}}$

How many distinct solutions are there to the following problem:

- $a + b + c = (2n+1) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z}.$
- $1 \leq a,b,c \leq n.$

**Clarification** 
Suppose that $~n = 5,~$ and consider the three solutions 
represented by $~(a,b,c) \in \{(1,5,5), (5,1,5), (5,5,1)\}.$

These three solutions are **not** to be considered distinct, because
(for example) you can generate each of the solutions $~(5,1,5)~$
and $~(5,5,1)~$ by simply permuting the components of the solution $~(1,5,5).$

So, suppose that you have Solution-1 and Solution-2 as solutions to the problem represented by the bullet points above.  Then, Solution-1 and Solution-2,  are to be considered distinct, if and only if Solution-2 does not represent a permutation of the components of Solution-1.

---

See my answer, which uses Stars and Bars theory, to obtain a closed form
expression for the number of distinct solutions.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145564/discussion-on-question-by-user2661923-revisit-abc-2n1-a-b-c-in-bbbz); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

No significant change.  Simply corrected a broken link to one of the references.

---

> How many distinct solutions are there to the following problem:

> - $a + b + c = (2n+1) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
> - $a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z}.$
> - $1 \leq a,b,c \leq n.$

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[Link-1](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[Link-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

For any set $~M~$ with a finite number of elements, let $~|M|~$ denote the
number of elements in the set $~M.$

Let $~D~$ denote the set of all solutions to the problem, under the
assumption that when Solution-2 is a permutation of Solution-1, that these
two solutions **are** to be regarded as distinct elements of $~D.~$

Let $~E~$ denote the subset of $~D~$ where **exactly** two of the three
components are equal.  Note that the set $~E~$ excludes the element of $~D~$ where
all three components are equal (if any).

Let $~F~$ denote the subset of $~D~$ where all three components are equal (if any).

Then the number of distinct solutions, where permuted solutions are not to be
regarded as distinct is:

$$\frac{|D| - |E| - |F|}{3!} + \frac{|E|}{3} + |F|. \tag1 $$

The expression in (1) above is explained as follows:

- $D ~\setminus ~(E \cup F) ~$ represents the set of solutions that contain exactly
  $~3~$ distinct components.  Each *distinct* solution will appear $~3!~$ times in
  the set $~D ~\setminus ~(E \cup F).$ 
  For example, if $~n = 5,~$ then the set $~D~$ will contain each of the following
  elements, which all represent the same answer:
  $(1,2,8), ~(1,8,2), ~(2,1,8), ~(2,8,1), ~(8,1,2), ~(8,2,1).$
- $E$ represents the set of solutions that contain exactly
  $~2~$ distinct components [i.e. when $~n = 5,~$ a solution like $~(5,5,1)~$].
  Each *distinct* solution will appear $~3~$ times in
  the set $~E.$

So, the entire problem reduces to computing a closed form expression for
each of $~|D|, ~|E|, ~|F|.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~|D|}$

I will parallel the approach given in
[The Model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded/4808542#4808542).

So, the task here is to compute the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = (2n+1) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$
- $x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3 \leq n.$

Basic Stars and Bars theory, as documented in **Link-1** at the start of this
answer, provides a formula, based on the assumption that the lower bound of the
variables is $~0,~$ rather than $~1.$  So, the first thing to do is employ a
change of variables, to adjust the lower bounds.

For $~i \in \{1,2,3\},~$ let $~y_i = x_i - 1.$

Then $~|D|~$ will equal the number of solutions to:

- $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = (2n+1) - 3 = (2n - 2).$
- $y_1, ~y_2, ~y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_1, ~y_2, ~y_3 \leq (n - 1).$

Following **The Model**:

- Let $~S~$ denote the set of all solutions, where the upper bound constraint
  [i.e. $~y_i \leq (n-1)~$ ] is ignored.
- For $~i \in \{1,2,3\}, ~$ let $~S_i~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where
  $~y_i \geq n.$

Then

$$|D| = |S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3|.$$

So,

- Let $~T_0~$ denote $~|S|.$
- Let $~T_1~$ denote $~|S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3|.$
- Let $~T_2~$ denote $~|S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3|.$
- Let $~T_3~$ denote $~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|.$

Then,

$$|D| = T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3.$$

You can examine **The Model** for a description of the Math involved.

You have that:

- $~\displaystyle T_0 = \binom{2n}{2}.$
- $~\displaystyle T_1 = 3 \times \binom{n}{2}.~$
- $~T_2 = 0, ~T_3 = 0.~$

Therefore,

$$|D| = \binom{2n}{2} - \left[ ~3 \times \binom{n}{2} ~\right] = \frac{n^2 + n}{2}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~|F|}$

The set $~F~$ represents the set of all solutions $~(a,b,c)~$ where
$~a + b + c = (2n+1),~$ and $~a = b = c.~$

Define the variable $~\alpha_n~$ so that

- If $~(2n+1)~$ is a multiple of $~3,~$ then $~\alpha_n = 1.$
- If $~(2n+1)~$ is not a multiple of $~3,~$ then $~\alpha_n = 0.$

Then $$|F| = \alpha_n.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~|E|}$

Consider the number of solutions to:

- $2x_1 + x_2 = (2n+1).$
- $x_1, ~x_2, \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$
- $x_1, ~x_2 \leq n.$

The above bullet pointed problem will have exactly one solution for each value
of $~x_1~$ that **is viable**.

For $~x_1 \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ you have that $~x_2 = (2n+1) - 2x_1.$

You must have $~x_2 \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.~$

So, clearly an upper bound for $~x_1~$ is $~x_1 = n \implies x_2 = 1.~$

The constraint that $~(2n+1) - 2x_1 \leq n~$ will be true if and only if

$\dfrac{n+1}{2} \leq x_1.$

Therefore, letting $~\lceil r\rceil ~$ denote the smallest positive integer
$~\geq r ~$ (i.e. the *ceiling* of $~r~$), you have that the lower bound for
$~x_1~$ is $~\displaystyle \left\lceil ~\frac{n+1}{2} ~\right\rceil.$

Therefore, the number of solutions to the bullet pointed problem above is

$\displaystyle (n+1) - \left\lceil ~\frac{n+1}{2} ~\right\rceil.$

From this, you have to deduct $~\alpha_n~$ which represents the solution (if any)
where $~x_1 = x_2.~$

Then,

$$|E| = 3 \times \left\{ ~(n+1) - \left\lceil ~\frac{n+1}{2} ~\right\rceil - \alpha_n ~\right\}. \tag2 $$

To illustrate the idea behind (2) above, assume that $~n = 4.~$ 
This implies that:

- $\displaystyle \left\lceil ~\frac{n+1}{2} ~\right\rceil = 3.$
- $~\alpha_n = 1.$
- $|E| = 3 \times \{5 - 3 - 1\} = 3 \times 1 = 3.$

The viable solutions to $~2x_1 + x_2 = 9~$ are given by 
$(x_1,x_2) \in \{~(3,3), (4,1) ~\}.~$

Then, in the set $~E~$ the solution $~(x_1,x_2) = (4,1)~$ will be represented by

$(a,b,c) \in \{~(4,4,1), ~(4,1,4), ~(1,4,4) ~\}.$

Further, the solution $~(x_1,x_2) = (3,3),~$ which represents 
$(a,b,c) = (3,3,3)~$ is excluded from set $~E.$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

- $\displaystyle |D| = \frac{n^2 + n}{2}.$
- $3 ~| ~(2n+1) \implies \alpha_n = 1.$ 
  $3 ~\not| ~(2n+1) \implies \alpha_n = 0.$
- $|F| = \alpha_n.$
- $\displaystyle |E| = 3 \times \left\{ ~(n+1) - \left\lceil ~\frac{n+1}{2} ~\right\rceil - \alpha_n ~\right\}.$

So, the number of distinct solutions, where different permutations of the same solution are not
considered distinct, is

$$\frac{|D| - |E| - |F|}{3!} + \frac{|E|}{3} + |F|. $$

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting this question; I thought it was a shame that it didn't fare better.  Interestingly, this seems to correspond to the number of integer partitions of $n+2$ with exactly 3 parts.  (I have some ideas for a bijection, but have not worked it out.)  This possibly equivalent partition question has a very nice solution, $\left\{ (n+2)^2/12 \right\}$ where braces denote nearest integer.  This was in the problems section of the _American Mathematical Monthly_ 47 (1940) pp664-665 in the context of counting essentially different integer side-length triangles with the same perimeter.

Comment: @BrianHopkins The mapping $(a,b,c)\mapsto (a+1,b+1,c+1)$ is a bijection from "integer triangles with perimeter $2n+1$" to "integer triangles with perimeter $2n+4$". Then, you can apply [this bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2252184/).

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Thanks much.  The direct bijection is then $(a,b,c) \mapsto ((a+b-c+1)/2, (a-b+c+1)/2, (-a+b+c+1)/2)$.